# hive understanding table creation

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am taking a [mooc](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DAT202.1x+3T2015/courseware/f0b45801068c404bb90b49853fe55ccd/1aaca55dcff640b99bc9ba93ac5fa4af/).

it told us to upload a few files from our PC to hdfs using below commands

```
azure storage blob upload local_path container data/logs/2008-01.txt.gz
```

I did the same.
later on when I typed below command in PUTTY secure shell  I was able to see that file

```
hdfs dfs -ls /data/logs
Found 6 items
-rwxrwxrwx   1     331941 2016-03-03 15:56 /data/logs/2008-01.txt.gz
-rwxrwxrwx   1     331941 2016-03-03 15:58 /data/logs/2008-02.txt.gz
-rwxrwxrwx   1     331941 2016-03-03 15:58 /data/logs/2008-03.txt.gz
-rwxrwxrwx   1     331941 2016-03-03 15:58 /data/logs/2008-04.txt.gz
-rwxrwxrwx   1     331941 2016-03-03 15:58 /data/logs/2008-05.txt.gz
-rwxrwxrwx   1     331941 2016-03-03 15:58 /data/logs/2008-06.txt.gz
```

then we started a `hive` terminal and first created a table and then inserted data into that table using

```
load data inpath '/data/logs' into TABLE rawlog;
```

Then we created an external table using below command

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cleanlog
(log_date DATE,
log_time STRING,
c_ip STRING,
cs_username STRING,
s_ip STRING,
s_port STRING,
cs_method STRING,
cs_uri_stem STRING,
cs_uri_query STRING,
sc_status STRING,
sc_bytes INT,
cs_bytes INT,
time_taken INT,
cs_user_agent STRING,
cs_referrer STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/data/cleanlog';
```

we inserted data into the table using

```
INSERT INTO TABLE cleanlog
SELECT *
FROM rawlog
WHERE SUBSTR(log_date, 1, 1) <> '#';
```

I exited out of hive and typed in below command

```
hdfs dfs -ls /data/logs
```

1. I dont see anything in that folder, why? where did uploaded log
   files go?
2. Where is the rawlog table? does it exist in the same folder? Why dont i see it?
3. Why do i see file 00000_0 in my cleanlog folder? is it the new
   table? If i type command

   hdfs dfs -ls /data/cleanlog

The output that i get is

```
Found 1 items
-rwxr-xr-x   1 sshuser supergroup   71323206 2016-03-03 16:11 /data/cleanlog/000000_0
```

################----------------------------------update 1

1. What would happen if load one more data file at `/data/logs/` and
   then run `select * from rawlog`? would it automatically pull data
   from the new file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to lose data in source folder, use external table. Have a look at this SE question:

[Difference between `load data inpath ` and `location` in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35473933/difference-between-load-data-inpath-and-location-in-hive/35478155#35478155)

> 1. I dont see anything in that folder, why? where did uploaded log files go?

They have been removed as data is loaded in table and you have used load data in path instead of external table

> 2. Where is the rawlog table? does it exist in the same folder? Why dont i see it?

Table definition does not exists in the folder where data resides. In your create table statement, you have already quoted the location of table data to be stored as /data/cleanlog

Have a look at below queries on where does hive stores files in hdfs.

[Where does Hive store files in HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058400/where-does-hive-store-its-files-in-hdfs)

[I have created a table in hive, I would like to know which directory my table is created in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178182/i-have-created-a-table-in-hive-i-would-like-to-know-which-directory-my-table-is)

> 3. Why do i see file 00000_0 in my cleanlog folder? is it the new table?

It's not new table. Execute this command in hive shell.

```
describe formatted <table_name>;
```

**EDIT:** Regarding incremental updates to table,follow the steps as per this [article](http://hortonworks.com/blog/four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive/) and this question : [Delta/Incremental Load in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188544/delta-incremental-load-in-hive)

Comment: let me look at your links. In mean type please answer my update 1 if possible

Comment: It should. Have a look at this article : http://hortonworks.com/blog/four-step-strategy-incremental-updates-hive/

Comment: i understood answers to most of my questions. I am a bit confused about q3. I created `cleanlog` table with `STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/data/cleanlog;' Therefore file 0000_0 which resides in that folder is the tabel cleanlog, right?  Also when i type `describe formatted cleanlog;` I get `Location:               wasb://azure@azure.blob.core.windows.net/data/cleanlog
`

Comment: that means /data =  wasb://azure@azure.blob.core.windows.net/data/ in HDFS comparable storage. azure blog storage server format will be in this format: wasb[s]://<containername>@<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>

Answer (score 1):

You used the `LOAD` command, which MOVED the files from their original location to the folder for the rawlog table (which by default will be `/hive/warehouse/rawlog`).

Comment: is there any easy way to access that folder using a secure shell? Would it be possible to answer the other questions too?